# $S$ linearly independent implies every vector in $Span(S)$ can be written as $c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...+c_ku_k$ for unique scalars $c_1,c_2,..., c_k$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure how to go about proving this problem. The title was too short for the whole problem, but the real question is:

Let $S = \{u_1, u_2,..., u_k\}$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that if $S$ is linearly independent, then every vector in $Span(S)$ can be written as $c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...+c_ku_k$ for unique scalars $c_1,c_2,..., c_k$.

This is for Linear Algebra, can anyone help me?

Comment: Latex this please!

Comment: this is my first time using this, i don't know what that means

Answer (score 1):

So the span of a set is by definition the set of all linear combinations (of elements of the set).

Now suppose $v\in \text{span}(S)$ can be written in two ways: $$v=c_1u_1+\dots +c_ku_k=d_1u_1+\dots +d_ku_k$$.

Subtract,  to get $$(c_1-d_1)u_1+\dots +(c_k-d_k)u_k=0$$.

Then by linear independence $c_i-d_i=0$ for each $i$.

Hence the coefficients are unique.